# How to use patsubst in makefile to do multiple substitutions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to generate list of object files from source files in my makefile using patsubst

```
OUT_DIR=Out/

SRC=../../../Client2.4/Client/src/BrokerModule/BrokerApp.cpp     
    ../../../Client2.4/Client/src/CommandMsgManager/CConfigModuleInfo.cpp

OBJ:= $(patsubst %src/%.cpp,${OUT_DIR}$%.o,$(SRC))
```

I want my `OBJ` variable to be

```
OBJ=Out/BrokerModule/BrokerApp.o Out/CommandMsgManager/CConfigModuleInfo.o
```

after patsubst but above patsubst is not producing the desired result. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with the usage of `patsubst`, see my suggestion as followed,

```
OUT_DIR=Out/

SRC=../../../Client2.4/Client/src/BrokerModule/BrokerApp.cpp \
../../../Client2.4/Client/src/CommandMsgManager/CConfigModuleInfo.cpp

# add the definition of src
src=../../../Client2.4/Client/src/

# Modify the definition of OBJ
OBJ:= $(patsubst ${src}%.cpp,${OUT_DIR}%.o,$(SRC))
```

Filtered out the prepended `${src}` and appended `.cpp`, and keep only
`BrokerModule/BrokerApp.cpp` & `CommandMsgManager/CConfigModuleInfo.cpp`.

And `%` is replaced by the text that matched the `%` in the previous step.

Comment: What do I do if I need to omit a particular object file from "OBJ". Let's say I don't want "CommandMsgManager/CConfigModuleInfo.o" to go into the library I am building?

Comment: @YogeshTyagi see the docs for [filter-out](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions)

Answer (score 0):

Patsubst can only handle patterns with one wildcard in it, unluckily. Moreover you are trying to take apart path names not the usual way at the file level. That means, as long as you neither know the prefix nor the postfix parts of the `/src/` in your strings, you are out of luck as you can never say 'replace unknown prefix and conserve unknown postfix' (or the other way round).
The usual solution is to 'know' the prefix:

```
OUT_DIR=Out/

SRC_PATH := ../../../Client2.4/Client/src

SRC=../../../Client2.4/Client/src/BrokerModule/BrokerApp.cpp     \
    ../../../Client2.4/Client/src/CommandMsgManager/CConfigModuleInfo.cpp

OBJ:= $(patsubst $(SRC_PATH)/%,${OUT_DIR}%,$(SRC))

$(info $(OBJ))
```

Another solution is to use e.g. the [GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) library of make functions (still beta but your problem can be solved):

```
include gmtt.mk

OUT_DIR=Out

SRC=../../../Client2.4/Client/src/BrokerModule/BrokerApp.cpp     \
    ../../../Client5.6/Client/src/CommandMsgManager/CConfigModuleInfo.cpp

strip-till-last-src = src/$(call implode,$(call down-to,src/,$(call explode,/,$1)))

OBJ:= $(foreach a-path,$(SRC),$(OUT_DIR)/$(call strip-till-last-src,$(a-path)))

$(info $(OBJ))
```